# What could be causing the  following error regarding MKTileCache?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

In the console, I'm seeing the following error when my application runs:

> void -[MKTileCache
>   synchronize](MKTileCache*,
>   objc_selector*) called while in
>   background

What could this error mean, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling a user interface function on a MKMapView from a background thread. All user interface functions should be called from the main thread; you can use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` from your background thread to signal the main thread to perform the appropriate selectors when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, @Anomie.  "Background" doesn't just refer to the main (UI) thread, versus *background* (worker) threads.  It can also be referring to apps that are backgrounded (not the active app).  I have an app that uses **MapKit**, and it does not support multitasking (closes on exit).  When I close my app, I always see this error.  It does not appear until the app has left the "foreground".  In my case, it's definitely **not** that some of my code is calling MapKit UI functions from worker *threads*.

So, to answer the question ... I see this, too.  It does not appear to be a problem.  I have not had any complaints from Apple, or anyone else.

I've tried nilling out my MapView's delegate, and the MapView, and the CLLocationManager's delegate, and the CLLocationManager, before exiting.  None of these solutions get rid of this message.